# Skype for Business API - How to find the endpointId

Tags: skype, lync

According to this document [(this)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/anonymousmeetingschedule), I need to provide the `endpointId=sip:ucapapp@metio.onmicrosoft.com` in order to generate the meeting URL.

I log in the Skype for Business on my desktop as first.name@OrganizationDomain.com.  How can I find out what is the `endpointId` or `sip`?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you log into the client as, add 'sip:' on to it.

The 'default' setup for Skype is firstname.lastname@orgdomain so it will be 'sip:firstname.lastname@orgdomain'.  You can rely on firstname.lastname@orgdomain as the rules can change or be setup differently (e.g. multiple org domains in a company or a different sip naming policy).